# blkid returns more information than expected

Tags: linux, uuid, libblkid

I'm following a recipe I created a couple of years ago, where at one point I need to use `blkid` to obtain a filesystem UUID.

I have this command noted, along with an expected example return value:

```
blkid -o export -s UUID /dev/mapper/thathost_crypt_md3
UUID=JNbF5T-vhSD-3aVv-intG-1Tk2-IEOZ-ABWXYZ
```

However, times have moved on and I'm no longer using Debian "wheezy" but instead "jessie". I see that on this more recent version of Debian I now have a different return value for the same command:

```
blkid -o export -s UUID /dev/mapper/thishost_crypt_sdb
DEVNAME=/dev/mapper/thishost_crypt_sdb
UUID=bddac63e-3510-4d24-a6fb-4d0a89abcdef
```

The man page for blkid seems to say that `-s UUID` should include only values matching that key, yet there's this extraneous `DEVNAME` in there, too.

I have a work-around, in that I can write this in both cases, but it seems strange the output structure should have changed:

```
echo "UUID=$(blkid -o value -s UUID /path/to/device)"
UUID=bddac63e-3510-4d24-a6fb-4d0a89abcdef
```

Package `util-linux` versions are 2.20.1-5.3 and 2.25.2-6, respectively.

Questions

1. Why the change in UUID shape, and does it matter?
2. Why the change in the output format?

Comment: I checked on the latest Gentoo with util-linux 2.28.2 as well as CentOS 6 with util-linux-ng 2.17.2 and I see the same difference as you do.  I can see there have been other parameter changes in between those version such as the version parameter changed from `-v` to `-V`.  Your solution seems consistent with the syntax changes done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DEVNAME is the alias of the device see [Persistent device name using alias](https://lwn.net/Articles/456697/)

Furthermore, it seems UUID is now required to be lowercase by International standards.

From [Type of Character generated by UUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258480/type-of-character-generated-by-uuid)

> To clarify, a UUID is actually a 128-bit value, not text or digits.
>   You could think of them as 128-bit unsigned integers.
>
> The latest international spec dated 2008-08 states (emphasis mine):
>
> > 6.5.4 Software generating the hexadecimal representation of a UUID shall not use upper case letters. NOTE – It is recommended that the
> >     hexadecimal representation used in all human-readable formats be
> >     restricted to lower-case letters. Software processing this
> >     representation is, however, required to accept both upper and lower
> >     case letters as specified in 6.5.2.

As for printing the UUID and the alias/DEVNAME

From util-linux/blkid.c is evident that DEVNAME is printed because you are using the `-o export`

```
} else if (ctl->output & OUTPUT_EXPORT_LIST) {
        if (num == 1 && devname)
            printf("DEVNAME=%s\n", devname);
```

So I suspected that without `-o export` it would only print the UUID, and indeed:

```
$blkid -s UUID /dev/sda2
/dev/sda2: UUID="67169dd7-f319-4402-a9b2-cebcf2f3657a"
$ blkid -o export -s UUID /dev/sda2
DEVNAME=/dev/sda2
UUID=67169dd7-f319-4402-a9b2-cebcf2f3657a
```

Comment: @roaima Added to the question.

Comment: Problem with omitting `-o export` is that the output format is of little use to me (I wanted the original `UUID=abc...xyz` style of output). I can either get two lines, one of which is the unwanted `DEVNAME=...` or I can have the `UUID` value which I then have to prefix with `UUID=`. The earlier revision of the program seems to have got it right and the newer version wrong. IMO, of course.

Comment: @roaima There are clearly changes `#define OUTPUT_PRETTY_LIST (1 << 3)  /* deprecated */`

Comment: So you're saying it's an intentional upstream code-change? Thank you. Appreciated.